# What is this purple box symbol on an Ordance Survey map?

Tags: maps, ordnance-survey

This symbol appears on a forest in an OS 1:50,000 Landranger map at SO 24799 27221. It doesn't appear in the map legend. It does not appear at the same point on the equivalent 1:25,000 Explorer map. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mauve symbol is new, and represents "Natural Resources Wales".

This appears to be [Open Access Land](https://naturalresources.wales/days-out/recreation-and-access-policy-advice-and-guidance/managing-access/open-access-land/?lang=en). It indicates the type of land bounded by a mauve outline (a fragment can be seen in your image).

It can be found on this [Ordnance Survey symbols PDF](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/legends/50k-raster-legend.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Whilst I don't doubt you, do you have a source for what the symbol means? It might possibly appear on a paper map legend (I don't have one to hand) but would expect it to at least appear on the OS website.

Comment: Although I've just noticed the similarity to the NRW logo so there's that. I wonder why it isn't on the Explorer map though.

Comment: I have added a link to where I found it (on their website). I can't explain why it isn't on the map legend, apart from being a new symbol.

Comment: Now I know where to look, it (ahem) actually is on the legend I was looking at, but it's quite small in my defence. Thanks.